# How to fork a specific gem version from Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I fork a specific gem version from this Github [page](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/pull/248)?

Comment: Your question seems to be about Git and Github rather than about Rails. I'd suggest trying to search some more and if appropriate rephrase your question to make it more about how to (verb) a pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gem 'faker', github: 'Makapoxa/faker', ref: '2c52d5'
```